# How does SCSS choose which class to use if more than one matches the element?

Tags: css, sass, less, scss-mixins

If I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="class1">
        class1
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        class2
    </div>
</div>
```

And LESS that looks like this:

```
.class1 {
    color: green;
}

.modal {
    .class1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Then how is it determined which properties get applied to the element?

In the above example, `class1` gets colored `red` but why? If I reorder the SCSS classes, then the `class1` text is STILL red so I don't understand how its determined which is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's specificity. Your class1 with the red color is more specific because it has class of .modal wrapping it, so red gets used over green.

This might help explain it better. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to Google it.

Comment: MDN is usually a very reliable source of info - in this case see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity